# kafka producer takes much more time when writing to more partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

we have 5 kafka brokers, replication factor 3, and 2 topics - T1 and T2.

T1 topic has 100 partitions, T2 has 6.

when writing with a kafka producer (using KafkaProducer.send()) to both T1 and T2, the time it takes to the producer.send() is ~1 sec.

But after increasing the number of partitions in T2 from 6 to 100, the total time of the send() increased to 20 sec.

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sending messages to all 100 partitions using keys? Or are they all ended up in earlier 6 partitions or a few of the newly introduced ones?

Comment: Not clear if you are sending keys or not

Comment: the messages were sent in round robin to all 100 partitions of T1 and T2. the key is null. 
Maybe the problem is too many connections to kafka? although it sounds strange since before we sent to 106 partitions and after we sent to 200 partitions. producing to 200 partitions doesn't sound so much